# showing that $f(x) \leq \alpha f(a) + \beta f(b)$

Tags: calculus

Show that if $f: R \rightarrow R$ is convex and $a,b \in dom f$, with $a < b$ then: 
$f(x)\leq \frac{b-x}{b-a} f(a) + \frac{x-a}{b-a}f(b)$. for all $x \in (a,b)$.

My book suggests that using Jensen's inequality I can prove this inequality. But I'm looking for other ways to prove this inequality. Is there any other techniques to prove it without using Jensen's inequality?

My second question is that, would the inequality holds if $x \in [a,b]$?

Comment: what properties does $f$  have   ?? continuity  ?  differentaibility ??

Comment: That holds for $convex$ functions (or can be taken as the definition for convexity). It does not hold generally.

Comment: Taking  $$ f=\begin{cases}  0  \; \; \; \; x \neq  0 \\    1  \; \; \; \; x  =  0  \end{cases}  $$
This does not hold, taking $(a,b)=(-1,1)$ and  $x=0$.

Comment: sorry, my bad. f is convex

Comment: @lino: How is convexity defined in your book?

Comment: @martin $f$ is convex iff: $f(a x + (1-a) y) \leq a f(x) + (1-a)f(y)$ and $0 \leq a \leq 1$

Comment: @lino Why not just try to use the definition of convexity to your function? All you need to do is to identify correctly $a,x,y$.

Comment: @A.G. Im trying that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For all $x\in [a,b]$,

$$x = \frac{b-x}{b-a} a + \frac{x-a}{b-a} b. $$